# Yelp Fusion API JSON Review Parsing

Tags: html, json, api, get, yelp

I want to display reviews on a webpage but have trouble with JSON parsing and formatting. Any help is greatly appreciated. I can handle the HTML and CSS markup, I just need to loop through each new review and get the reviewer, reviewtext, pictureurl, etc.

So far, it's only able to get the amount of reviews. I'm new to JSON and am having trouble parsing the reviews and getting the format right.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Ilan's Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>

   <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="results">

                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
   </div>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>
         var myurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/financial-sanity-now-los-angeles-2/reviews";

         $.ajax({
            url: myurl,
            headers: {
             'Authorization':'Bearer API-KEY-GOES-HERE',
         },
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                // Grab the results from the API JSON return
                var totalresults = data.total;
                // If our results are greater than 0, continue
                if (totalresults > 0){
                    // Display a header on the page with the number of results
                    $('#results').append('<h5>We discovered ' + totalresults + ' reviews!</h5>');
                    // Itirate through the JSON array of 'reviews' which was returned by the API
                    $.each(data.reviews[id], function(id, review) {
                        // Store each review object in a variable
                        var id = review.id;
                        var reviewtext = reviews[id].text;
                        var reviewrating = reviews[id].rating;
                        // Append our result into our page
                        $('$results').append(reviewtext + reviewrating + reviews);
                  });
                } else {
                    // If our results are 0; no reviews were returned by the JSON so we display on the page no results were found
                    $('#results').append('<h5>We discovered no results!</h5>');
                }
            }
         });     

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor mistakes with the code, but it's fine; your each function was a bit messy and you accidentally used $results as a reference which should've been #results; but it's all good your getting it!

Check out the code below (note Yelp only allows 3 reviews to be fetched; so when you see 8 total; it won't fetch more than 3);

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Ilan's Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>

   <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="results">

                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
   </div>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>
         var myurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/financial-sanity-now-los-angeles-2/reviews";

         $.ajax({
            url: myurl,
            headers: {
             'Authorization':'Bearer API-KEY-GOES-HERE',
         },
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                // Grab the results from the API JSON return
                var totalresults = data.total;
                // If our results are greater than 0, continue
                if (totalresults > 0){ console.log(data);
                    // Display a header on the page with the number of results
                    $('#results').append('<h5>We discovered ' + totalresults + ' reviews!</h5>');
                    // Itirate through the JSON array of 'reviews' which was returned by the API
                    $.each(data.reviews, function(i, item) {
                        // Store each review object in a variable
                        var author = item.user.name;
                        var reviewtext = item.text;
                        var reviewrating = item.rating;
                        // Append our result into our page
                        $('#results').append('Author: <b>' + author + '</b><br> Review: ' + reviewtext + '<br>Rating: ' + reviewrating + ' <hr>');
                  });
                } else {
                    // If our results are 0; no reviews were returned by the JSON so we display on the page no results were found
                    $('#results').append('<h5>We discovered no results!</h5>');
                }
            }
         });     

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a boss. This is exactly what I was looking for. I was messing around with the code and I got so close but I think I overcomplicated it.

Comment: Very welcome, coincidentally the code snippet you used to modify was originally my code from another answer (seeing the title of your original snippet); I’m happy to be able to assist! The more you practice the better you’ll get; keep up the good work! - Ilan

Comment: I saw your code and I figured the reviews aren't too far off! :)
I am trying to get it working with the Facebook API which has a different authentication process. I think you request a token, then use that in another GET request to pull the reviews, but I don't have the manage_page permission yet for the business I'm trying to pull the reviews from because the app is under review, I think I might just try for google reviews and yelp and call it a day lol, I also heard the facebook API will stop allowing requests from pages, do you know anything about this?
https://pastebin.com/Jr8mSJCe

Comment: Nope, it's for sure do-able; I wrote an API for this a while ago: https://www.reviewsmaker.com/api/demo/facebook/ it's always best to use the native API as workarounds can get a little messy but if there's a will there always is a way.